# C# ConvertBack from a binding column of textbox to a JObject

Tags: c#, json, wpf, binding

GoodDay!
I'm not good with wpf and binding, i need your help. I have already bind a Json Object (JObject) to a Column of TextBox.

```
<TextBox Width="250" Text="{Binding Path=Property, Converter={StaticResource jPropertyConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I can show properly the data of the Jobject when i start my wpf window, now i need to ConvertBack the data modified when i modify one of the textbox of the columns, from that TextBox to the JObject, and the related JValue.

```
public class JPropertyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is JProperty)
        {
            JToken valoreProperty = (value as JProperty).Value;
            if ((valoreProperty is JValue))
                return (valoreProperty as JValue).Value;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ??
    }
}
```

I can change the Value of the "leaves" of this JObject tree like:

```
(valoreProperty as JValue).Value = "Hello!";
```

How can i change the "leaves" of this JObject tree in the convert back?
Sorry for my english.
Thanks and bye

EDIT:
Thanks dbc! It works, many thanks!

Now i need to show in another column, every lenght of the value inside of the textbox, obviously if i change the value in the texbox the relative lenght value will change too.

I tried:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Lunghezza2" IsReadOnly="True"  Width="50" Binding="{Binding Path=Property.Value.Value.toString().Length, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"  />
```

or in another way with a converter, passing a JProperty

```
 public class LengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is JProperty)
        {
            JToken jValue = (value as JProperty).Value;
            if ((jValue is JValue) && (jValue as JValue).Value != null)
                return (jValue as JValue).Value.ToString().Length.ToString();
            else
                return "0";
        }
        else
            return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But every try didn't works when i change the textbox value, any tips?
Many thanks again!

Comment: the question is not clear can you explain this in a simpler way?

Comment: up the Edit. Second part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345702/how-can-i-bind-the-length-of-a-textbox-to-a-textblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a converter for this purpose.  Assuming your `Property` property returns a `JProperty`, you can bind directly to `JProperty.Value.Value`

```
            <TextBox Name="PropertyTextBox" 
                     Text="{Binding Path=Property.Value.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                     />
```

If you want to disable the `TextBox` if the bound `Property` is not a "simple" `JProperty` (one with just a `JValue` for its value), you can do:

```
            <TextBox Name="PropertyTextBox" 
                     Text="{Binding Path=Property.Value.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                     IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Property, Converter={StaticResource IsSimpleJPropertyConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                     />
```

Using the converter

```
public class IsSimpleJPropertyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is JProperty)
        {
            JToken jValue = (value as JProperty).Value;
            if (jValue is JValue)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Up 4 the edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345702/how-can-i-bind-the-length-of-a-textbox-to-a-textblock